# D3 - Vertical axis is not displaying correctly

Tags: d3.js

I have a CSV file containing the French population by department. I can correctly display a map colored with population density but I encounter problems with the associated legend.

You can see the current result here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y26JT.jpg

After loading the CSV, here is my code to add the legend :

```
legend = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(525, 150)')
    .attr('id', 'legend');

legend.selectAll('.colorbar')
    .data(d3.range(9))
    .enter().append('svg:rect')
    .attr('y', function(d) { return d * 20 + 'px'; })
    .attr('height', '20px')
    .attr('width', '20px')
    .attr('x', '0px')
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "q" + d + "-9"; })
    .attr('stroke', 'none');

legendScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(csv, function(e) { return +e.POP; })])
    .range([0, 9 * 20]);

legendAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(legendScale)
    .orient('right')
    .tickSize(1);       

legendLabels = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(550, 150)')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(legendAxis);
```

Colors are obtain using ColorBrewer CSS (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/lib/colorbrewer)

I have two problems:

- The Hyphen '-' (a SVG line) is not displayed for each value of my axis
- I cannot choose the number of values in my axis, I would like one at the beginning of each color block.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your solution isn't showing the 'hyphen' (svg lines) is because you have the tickSize set very small. Try not setting it and it will default to 6 (according to the API docs - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes).

To choose the number of values in your axis, you can add a call to ".ticks(N)", where N is the number of ticks you want. D3 will try to show that many ticks. You could also call ".tickValues([...])" and pass in the exact array of values to use for the ticks.

Here's a JSFiddle that corrects the issues in your example: http://jsfiddle.net/TRkGK/3/

And a sample of the part that fixes your issues:

```
var legendAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(legendScale)
   .orient('right')
   .tickSize(6) // Tick size controls the width of the svg lines used as ticks
   .ticks(9); // This tells it to 'try' to use 9 ticks
```

UPDATED:

You also want to make sure you're setting the CSS correctly. Here's what I use:

```
.y.axis line {  stroke: #ccc; }
.y.axis path {  display: none; }
```

In your example, when you add the larger tickSize, you are seeing the path in which the tick lines are defined. If you hide the path and give the lines a color, you'll see the ticks rather than the area in which the ticks are defined.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer, it solves one of my two problems. The number of values is now more elegant but I cannot still see the svg lines, with tickSize(6) the vertical line is just larger as you can see here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/qFZhb.jpg

Comment: Updated my answer. Check out the CSS in the JSFiddle. You are seeing the path being drawn on top of the ticks. If you hide the path and give the lines a stroke, you'll see them correctly.

Comment: Ah, also I was using Chrome. It should work now in FF with this link: http://jsfiddle.net/TRkGK/3/

Comment: I cannot see the result now. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad I could help, learning D3 is a bit of an adventure. Remember to accept my answer if you're satisfied :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be a css issue, did you look at reblace's css in his fiddle?

Comment: I do not mention it in my answer to reblace but I cannot see anything in the result windows of his jsfiddle. Do you see any result ?

Comment: Ok, it is now working with reblace CSS :

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    shape-rendering: crispedges;
    stroke: #000000;
}